# Class 'Shanty_Mongo_Document' not found

Tags: php, zend-framework, mongodb

Trying to play with Shanty Mongo, and Zend (I am new to both) but I keep getting:

```
"Fatal error: Class 'Shanty_Mongo_Document' not found
    in /var/www/dbtz/application/models/User.php on line 4"
```

First, the indexAction of my controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->view->pageTitle = "Add User";

    $form = new Application_Form_UserAdd();

    if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
        $formData = $this->_request->getPost();
        if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
            $user = new Application_Model_User();
            $user->username = $formData['username'];

            $user->save();
            exit;
        } else {
            $form->populate($formData);
        }
    }        

    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

Second, the model:

```
class Application_Model_User extends Shanty_Mongo_Document
{
    protected static $_db = 'dbtz';
    protected static $_collection = 'user';

    public static $_requirements = array(
        'username' => 'Required',
        'password' => 'Required',
    );
}
```

I have the library/Shanty directory symlinked into the library folder. This is how I have the Zend library included, and it works fine.

tree of the library folder:

```
/var/www/dbtz/library# tree -l
.
├── Shanty -> /var/www/libs/Shanty-Mongo/library/Shanty/
│   ├── Mongo
│   │   ├── Collection.php
│   │   ├── Connection
│   │   │   ├── Group.php
│   │   │   └── Stack.php
│   │   ├── Connection.php
│   │   ├── Document.php
│   │   ├── DocumentSet.php
│   │   ├── Exception.php
│   │   ├── Iterator
│   │   │   ├── Cursor.php
│   │   │   └── Default.php
│   │   └── Validate
│   │       ├── Array.php
│   │       ├── Class.php
│   │       └── StubTrue.php
│   ├── Mongo.php
│   └── Paginator
│       └── Adapter
│           └── Mongo.php
└── Zend -> /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/
...
```

Comment: Not too familiar with Zend, but can you hook temporarily into the autoloader system to see where it is looking for class files?

Comment: Did you install the php driver? ( [Here detailed instructions](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/PHP+Language+Center))

Comment: Make sure you have placed the library files in the correct place

Comment: @nixy Yes I have installed the mongo php driver.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. needed to add

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Shanty_"
```

to my application.ini